# Can I please get some help creating vertical buttons?

Tags: html, css, button

I am trying to create a vertical set of buttons using a  element, and it is not working. I found the code on this website: https://alextheedom.wordpress.com/code-and-stuff/creating-buttons-from-ul-element/

This is my HTML Code:

```
     <aside class="sidebar" role="complementary">
   <ul class="homepagebutton">
     <li><a href="https://www.google.com">Donate</a></li>
     <li><a href="https://www.google.com">Volunteer</a></li>
     <li><a href="https://www.google.com">Shop</a></li>
   </ul>
 </aside>
```

This is my CSS Code:

```
.homepagebutton {
list-style: none;
text-align: center;
background-color: #000000;
margin-bottom: 2%;
width: 10%;
line-height: 4%;
}

.homepagebutton li a{
text-decoration: none;
color: #FFFFFF;
display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try it:

```
.homepagebutton li {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 10%;
    margin-bottom:1%;
}
.homepagebutton li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    background-color: #000000;
    line-height: 440%;
}
.homepagebutton li a:hover{background: #666;}
```

[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/jikeytang/qv8a3uLw/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
#homepagebutton {
float: left;
list-style: none;
text-align: center;
background-color: #000000;
margin-bottom: 2%;
width: 10%;
line-height: 4%;
}

#homepagebutton li a{
text-decoration: none;
color: #FFFFFF;
display: block;
}
```

You have used the ID for homepagebutton and therefore your css should reference `#homepagebutton` rather than `.homepagebutton` which would be a class.

Alternatively you can leave your CSS as is and change the html to read class instead of id.

Comment: I changed my ul from id to class. Am I correct in assuming that there is no difference between using class and id in this situation?

Comment: the main difference is that you can only use each unique ID once per page whereas you can use a class over and over if for example you wanted to show these homepage buttons elsewhere on the page.

Answer (score 0):

In your stylesheet, you are referring to HTML elements that have 'homepagebutton' class, but in your HTML, your list has an ID 'homepagebutton'. Replace the `.homepagebutton` with `#homepagebutton`